# How to find attributes from a function in machine learning?

Tags: functions, machine-learning

I have started learning machine learning. I have a question in mind. Is it possible to know how many attributes or features a certain model has by seeing its equation? Suppose a function given below:

$$f(x) = 2.54  x^2 + a  x + 3.10
$$
How many attributes or features does this model have in machine learning?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it from two different perspectives

> Non-linear model

In this case, there's only one feature $x$

> Linear model

If you call $z_0 = x^0 = 1$, $z_1=x^1$, $z_2 = x^2$ then your model becomes

$$
g(z_0,z_1, z_2) = 2.54z_2 + a z_1 + 3.10 z_0
$$

which is a linear model with three features: $z_0, z_1$ and $z_2$

Comment: Thank you! I understand now..